# Posting json string to c# mvc method

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a json string (json representation of a javascript array), which I want to pass to a C# controller method. However, I am either seeing the c# method parameter as null or the breakpoint not being hit.

Here is the js code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PersistSelections",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  { "json": JSON.stringify(selectedItems) }

        })
```

Where "seleteditems" is just a javascript colleciton.

My c# code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void PersistSelections([FromBody] string json)
    {

    }
```

However, this is likely not the right way of doing this? I am always seeing the json parameter is null.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to take advantage of the model binding instead of trying to post and parse the JSON yourself.

Create a model of the items to be sent

```
public class ItemModel {
    //...include the desired properties

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

next update the action to expect the items

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PersistSelections([FromBody] ItemModel[] items) {
    //access posted items
}
```

and lastly update the client to post the json data

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/PersistSelections",
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  JSON.stringify(selectedItems)
})
```

The framework's built in model binder should parse and bind the posted JSON and populate the objects in the controller

Comment: You said, 'A better approach would be to take advantage of the model binding instead of trying to post and parse the JSON yourself'. I get this but I have a controller method which takes different types of Json strings. In this case, I can't bind to any specific model. How to receive this data in controller? As in, what type of controller method param I should be using for this? Is there any generic type that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using contentType as application/json that's why default modelbinder is not working. if you want to fix the issue create a class let say model

```
  Public Class MyModel{
    Public string Json {get;set;}
   }
```

And in controller use

```
[HttpPost]
    public void PersistSelections(MyModel model)
    {

    }
```